# Excel export is not working with WebControl table

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my application i have bind sql data source to grid view, on click of export button i took gridviews datasource in datatable and created webControl table and write that control to xls file. but i am getting follwowing error:

> *Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.*

My code is as follows:

```
HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
Response.Clear();
string StudNm = Request["hidStudnm"];
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "StudentPasswordReport" + ".xls");

Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table tblRept;
tblRept = CreateTable(exportDt);
tblRept.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
```

please tell me why this error is occurred and how can i resole this error

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
    DataTableToExcel(exportDt);

    private void DataTableToExcel(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
        GridView gridView = new GridView();
        gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
        gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        gridView.DataBind();
        gridView.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        htmlWriter.Close();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Write(writer.ToString());
        Response.End();
}
```